# ERDAS 2011 and OpenOffice

Tags: erdas-imagine

Is it possible to connect ERDAS 2011 with tools of OpenOffice instead of Office tools? I need to send a map composition made in ERDAS to Presentation of OpenOffice. I don't have Word or Power Point and I don't want to install it. I use OpenOffice.

Or is there other any way to send/export my map composition from ERDAS to OpenOffice.

I sent my map to JPEG, it works but resolution is bad to print it out and even to have it as the image in jpeg.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Which version of OpenOffice / LibreOffice are you using?

Comment: I use OpenOffice.org 3.3.0

Comment: export as a high res tiff and import it in open office to get better resolution output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly: if your map is pixelated, whatever GIS you are using, try setting the paper to a lareger size and upping the DPI (dots per inch).  This presupposes you are using vector data and/or the resolution of any raster is suitable for printing at the size you want.  I wouldn't recommend using anything less than 300 dpi and I think printers prefer 600 dpi.  It's been a LONG time since I used ERDAS but I have the feeling that it defaults to 200 dpi and probably A4 paper.  So long as you don't print on anything bigger than A4, that ought to be just about OK, but will be poor if you want to zoom in on an image (or shine it up on a wall in PowerPoint or OO-Impress.

If you get your map-output image resolution right, you don't need any direct (programmed) connection between your GIS and OO.  Just import the image to your slide.

Comment: Yay! It works! Many thanks for such clear explanation, now I understand what is DPI and what it is for. So in ERDAS 2011 before to send a map to JPeg: in Options DPU (in ERDAS it is DPU) is 300 inches and 'Percentage Change from Screen Resolution' is needed to be changed from 100 to 200. To enable the latter 'Use Screen resolution for 2D and Map Views' needs to be unticked then Apply and send a map to Jpeg. Resolution is changed everything looks good! I also kept the paper size as A4. And yes, I don't need direct connection between GIS and OO. Thank you very much! All the best! :)